# How to set focus on first input field using jQuery in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I can set focus on first input, that works in all browsers(except IE):

```
  $('#login').on('shown', function () {
  $(login).find('input:visible:first').focus();
})
```

I need to call it after Bootstrap modal showing will be finished, so I'm calling it in shown function.

Also tried this code(not working):

```
 $('#sign_up').on('shown', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
    $(sign_up).find('input:visible:first').focus();
  }, 100);
 ///working everywhere except explorer
$('#login').on('shown', function () {
  $('#user_email').focus();
})
```

Comment: i think u are missing # in your second code... not sure if this causing the problem but u can try it out....
$('#login').find('input:visible:first').focus();
or
$(this).find('input:visible:first').focus();

Comment: Is `shown` a Bootstrap-specific event?

Comment: @bipen, everything is working in all browser, so you think that is reason why in IE it is not focus ?

Comment: @Blender, no I think. just mentioned it to explain why I'm calling shown function.

Comment: @bipen, I think it just don't understand FIRST attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formfocus() {
  document.getElementById('element').focus();
}
window.onload = formfocus;
</script>
```

[JAVASCRIPT DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dvPN9/4/)

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#element').focus();
});
```

[JQUERY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dvPN9/3/)

JQUERY FOR IE 8

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('#element').focus();
  }, 10);
});
```

[IE 8 DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/dvPN9/6/)

HTML

```
<form>
  <input id="element" />
  <input />
  <input />
</form>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){function formfocus() {
      document.getElementById('user_email').focus();
    }});` not working.

Comment: afshin, thanks, but I can't get why it is not working. I'm using Bootstrap modals and calling this code on `shown` event.

Comment: I tested in IE8. It is not working there, but thanks for info about IE9)

Comment: I found problem - problem is in Bootstrap.

Comment: I know the reason, but don't know solution. I tried to call `alert('hello')` on `shown` event and it isn't calling in IE(

Comment: Here is documentation - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: I don't know what's problem exactly because I don't have IE8 try but try show event maybe helpful

Comment: Not working still. Maybe I will write them an email into support.